# Всплывающее окно после успешной отправки формы

Tags: javascript, php, form

Подскажите как реализовать всплывающую подсказку после успешной отправки формы, обработчик формы на php в этом и проблема, js вообще никак не обрабатывает форму, какие есть варианты поделитесь....

```html
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Новая заявка';
$mail->Body    = 'Hаименование организации: ' .$name . '<br>Номер телефона: ' .$phone. '<br>Почта: ' .$email. '<br>Адрес организации: ' .$addr. '<br>Сообщение: ' .$msg;
$mail->AltBody = '';



if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: thank-you.html');
}
?>

концовка файла, эту html страницу не выводит...(((
```

Comment: <<концовка файла, эту html страницу не выводит>>-конечно он её не выведет. Ведь через `header` Вы отправляете браузер на другую страницу.

Comment: Как тогда сделать ??

Comment: Где вы хотите показывать всплывашку? На thank-you.html или на странице, с которой отправляете форму. Внесите немного ясности в вопрос.

Comment: Хотелось бы на странице формы, чтоб не было перехода куда либо